# MRAID and iOS/Android

Tags: ios, html, ads, mraid

I am currently working on a MRAID compliant advertisement SDK and am finding it difficult to find resources on what exactly makes it MRAID compliant.

I have had a look at the IAB document:

```
http://www.iab.net/media/file/IAB_MRAID_v2_FINAL.pdf
```

But find this bulky, confusing and not to the point. I was wondering if anybody had better resources for this on the iOS and Android front for the compliance, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what you're working on. Are you trying to build an SDK that implements the standard in order for it to display ad's (creatives in MRAID terminology)?

If so I've implemented an SDK for Android that does just that. The document is one of the best resources out there. I suggest you go over it call by call and just use the JSBridge to implement the functionality.

Also be aware that the standard says nothing about how the ad is actually delivered to the device so how you want to do that is up to you.